# How to know when Lib-GDX HTML has loaded?

Tags: gwt, libgdx

How can I know through javascript that my Lib-GDX game has loaded. I would like to display stuff in the html before it loads. This is because the loading screen takes a couple seconds to load.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably post a runnable that does the cleanup in the HtmlLauncher. Runnables should only be processed in the main loop, i.e. after pre-loading is done.

Alternatively, if you want to do this in plain JS in index.html, add a dom change listener to the element with the id `embed-html`

Comment: Oh, that is an interesting and probably better way to do it. I will accept your answer and leave mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

You just have to check for a `canvas` in the `embed-html` `div`.

```
var node = document.getElementById('embed-html'),

htmlContent = node.innerHTML,
if(htmlContent.includes("canvas"){
    //it is now loaded
}
```

Run this in `setTimeout()`